# Laravel 4 Boolean in model

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4

I have been trying to use a Boolean value in laravel `TINYINT(1)`. However although it works fine for `true`/`1` it cannot understand `false`/`0`. So if I change it to false it will still read as true as it seems `Eloquent` ignores the false value.

I have tried strings, ints and normal Boolean but they all have the same effect.

```
// I pull in the info kind of like this
$fields = Input::all();
$model->never_expires = $field['never_expires'];
$model->save();
```

never_expires is fillable within the model and uses a laravel boolean (created from the schema generator) which translates to a `TINYINT(1)`.

I'm sure its something super simple I am missing, but I just can't see it.

Comment: Technically, the TINYINT(1) is an integer. Why not try casting your boolean to an integer on assignment? `$model->never_expires = (int) $field['never_expires'];` and let PHP handle converting true/false to 1/0.

Comment: Already tried that, with int, string and Boolean. The problem is that Eloquent does not want to put 0 in the database for whatever reason.

Comment: Try doing a manual insert and see what happens.  This may not even be a Laravel issue.

Comment: Success with manual. Giving up on there being a simple solution and am going to check out the source code and see if there is anything that might tell me why this happens.

Comment: can u `dd(Input::all())` and paste the output for when u pass true and false?

Comment: Input had no problems, it was fine until it was passed to eloquent.

Comment: @JordanRamstad Just wanted to see what is the type of the variable you're assigning to the field (int, bool, string, null) and see if I can come up with something.

Comment: coming from the form its is a number string `'1'` for false since its a checkbox it just does not appear but I adjust it before passing it to eloquent (so if it is set, 1, if not 0).

Answer (score 0):

I found that only by manually adjusting the `Boolean` row it would actually update, so I added the following to the model.

```
public function setExpire($never_expires)
{
    if ($never_expires == 1)
    {
        DB::table($this->table)->where('id', $this->id)->update(['never_expires' => 1]);
    }
    else
    {
        DB::table($this->table)->where('id', $this->id)->update(['never_expires' => 0]);
    }

    return true;
}

protected function getHasExpireAttribute()
{
    return $this->never_expires;
}
```

Basically I used the public function `setExpire` to handle adding the expiry and use `has_expire` as a fake element to get it (to ensure that I know its only my function saving anything to that column).

Very dirty way to do it since you basically do 2 mysql queries in one save, but it works.

I won't be using this answer as the answer, I still believe there must be a better way, but spent too long on such a tiny problem.